# How to make html div block look like cut? Example inside

Tags: html, css

I have to make a page with blocks which look like that :

[image]

How I can transform those div blocks? Text or other content in blocks should be normal, not transformed like background.

Comment: With CSS maybe you can..... What have you tried?

Comment: I tried like that [link](http://jsfiddle.net/2bZAW/3448/) but border after background is overlaying on next background after that.

Comment: Maybe try looking here :-) http://generatedcontent.org/post/26407228072/split-feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS3 transforms, and to keep contents from appearing transformed, you transform them the opposite of their parent.

For example:

```
.outer{
    transform: skew(0deg, -5deg) ;
}
.inner{
    transform: skew(0deg, 5deg) ;
}
```

Here's a [**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ggek7xug/4/) demonstrating this.

HTH,
-Ted

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pseudo element, absolute position it then use the [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) property to `rotate` the DIV.  I have updated the jsFiddle you linked to in comments with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/2bZAW/3449/

```css
div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: -25px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 110%;
    background-color: yellow;
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
```